# Is $T^2 \# \mathbb RP^2\cong \mathbb RP^2\# \mathbb RP^2\# \mathbb RP^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-interpretation

I was reading a little about how to imagine the projective plane and I have some weird intuition that says $T^2 \# \mathbb RP^2\cong \mathbb RP^2\# \mathbb RP^2\# \mathbb RP^2$. Is this true, and if so, is there any way to prove it formally using topology?

**Added.** If so, what is it? I've taken a first course on topology, so I know the basic definitions.

Comment: true and there is a way, yes

Comment: @janmarqz could you tell me what it is?

Comment: i would like you could read about Conways Zip Proof or read C.Kosniowsky's book

Comment: Also Stillwell's book "Classical topology and combinatorial group theory"

Comment: The answer is yes! And you can find a nice, simple proof with pictures here:   [http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/3/16/classifying-surfaces-cliff-notes-version](http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/3/16/classifying-surfaces-cliff-notes-version) (Scroll to the bottom of the page.)